# On the positivity of solutions of the differential inequality $y'' - y < 0$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

In a [recent Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3935226/42969) the following was demonstrated:

> Let $f: [0, 1] \to \Bbb R$ be twice differentiable with $f(0) = f(1) = 0$ and $f''(x) - f(x) < 0$ for $0 < x < 1$. Then $f(x) > 0$ for $0 < x < 1$.

There is a simple proof by noticing that $f$ cannot attain its minimum at a point $c \in (0, 1)$.

I then tried a different approach. Set $h = f - f''$ and let us assume for simplicity that $f''$ is continuous, so that $h$ is continuous as well. Then $f$ is a solution of the differential equation
$$ \tag{*}
 y'' - y = -h \, .
$$
The solutions of the homogenous equation $y'' - y = 0$ are $y_1(x) = \cosh(x)$ and $y_2(x) = \sinh(x)$, and the method of variation of constants (or an educated guess) shows that the general solution of $(*)$ is
$$
 y(x) = C_1 \cosh(x) + C_2 \sinh(x) - \int_0^x \sinh(x-t) h(t) \, dt \, .
$$
Together with the conditions $f(0) = f(1) = 0$ we get that
$$ \tag{**}
 \boxed{f(x) = \frac{\sinh(x)}{\sinh(1)} \int_0^1 \sinh(1-t) h(t)\, dt - \int_0^x \sinh(x-t) h(t) \, dt \, . \, }
$$
So the following is true:

> Let $h: [0, 1] \to \Bbb R $ be continuous and positive, and define $f: [0, 1] \to \Bbb R$ via $(**)$. Then $f(x) > 0$ for $x \in (0, 1)$

and I wonder if this can be seen directly, without going back the differential inequality $f'' < f$.

In $(**)$ we have the difference of two positive terms (if $0 < x < 1$), so it is not immediately obvious that $f(x) > 0$. If we split the first integral in two parts then we get
$$
 f(x) = \int_0^x \left( \frac{\sinh(x)}{\sinh(1)} \sinh(1-t) - \sinh(x-t)\right) h(t) \, dt
 + \frac{\sinh(x)}{\sinh(1)} \int_x^1 \sinh(1-t) h(t)\, dt
$$
but now it is not obvious (at least not to me) that the first integral is positive for $0< x < 1$.

So my question is:

> Given that $h$ is continuous and positive on $[0, 1]$, can $(**)$ be written in a form which allows to conclude that $f(x) > 0$ for $0 < x < 1$?

This would provide an alternative (albeit more complicated) proof of the initial statement.

Comment: $\frac{\sinh(x)}{\sinh(1)} \sinh(1-t) - \sinh(x-t)=\sinh(t)(\cosh(x)-\coth(1)\sinh(x))\ge0$ (for $0\le x\le1$), using the trig-like identities.

Comment: @Chrystomath: I tried various trigonometric calculations but surely have missed something. You are welcome to elaborate that in an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are trig-like identities for hyperbolic functions:

$$\sinh(x-t)=\sinh(x)\cosh(t)-\cosh(x)\sinh(t)$$

$$\sinh(1-t)=\sinh(1)\cosh(t)-\cosh(1)\sinh(t)$$

Hence \begin{align}\frac{\sinh(x)}{\sinh(1)} \sinh(1-t) - \sinh(x-t)&=\sinh(x)\cosh(t)-\coth(1)\sinh(x)\sinh(t)\\
&\quad-\sinh(x)\cosh(t)+\cosh(x)\sinh(t)\\[1mm]
&=\sinh(t)(\cosh(x)-\coth(1)\sinh(x))\ge0\end{align} since $\cosh(x)-\coth(1)\sinh(x)=\cosh(x)(1-\tanh(x)/\tanh(1))\ge0$ for $0\le x\le1$.

Comment: Great, thank you!